# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl half page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, transition, viewcontroller

I'm displaying an UIViewController by the following way:

```
MyViewController *myVc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[myVc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[self presentModalViewController:myVc animated:YES];
```

If I'm drawing the `MyViewController`'s view the transition affect only half a page (What I do want).

In my case I'm drawing the entire `MyViewController`'s view so the transition takes affect at the entire view

If I'm drawing only half a view the transition takes affect on half of the screen but I still have 'dead area' that is being shown and isn't drawn.

[image]

My question is how can the transition take affect only for half of the screen (as in the picture) but I still be able to draw the entire view so even if the transition shows only half of the screen, all the shown area will be drawn

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: Did you have any issues with the toolbar while implementing the page curl feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem here? Populate content in the `modalView` in such a way that the visible area is utilized. If I am not wrong, the `modalPageCurl` effect has no option to set the extent of curl (or how much of the screen it should occupy).

So I suggest you skip this approach & focus on trying to cover (or utilize) as much screen is available...

Comment: The OP did not ask how to use the modalView in such a way...they asked what I am in interested in knowing too...since `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` detects how much of the underlying view is in use and then rolls up appropriately, how do we cover -- or darken, etc, the area under it's flap.

Answer (score 4):

iOS only uses the first-level children of the UIView to decide where to position the partial page curl. That allows you to add a 2nd level child view with a frame of e.g. (0, -50, 320, 100) that slips into the area you call the "dead area".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the posters here and in related threads are having problems because they are trying to decorate the background of the underlying view using another view, such as an image view.  The correct way to set a background - and which will not affect the page curl, is to actually set the background.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //BG
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StitchTileBG.png"]];
}
```

Leave using views and such for actual user interface elements

Answer (score -2):

```
MyViewController * myVc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipPage" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:myVc.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```