# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl, less amount of curl

Tags: ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

Is there any way to limit the amount of curling of that kind of presentation? I know that system automatically curls depending on content inside view of the viewcontroller that we present modally in taht way.

But thta's not working for me in my **iPad** app. I have only a little table at the bottom right corner of the view but the page curls more than a half.

I double checked all properties and autoresizing masks without find a solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: check the leaves project here that will help you for the animation for the same curl. Actually this application is implemented the animation on the basis of the touch but you can get the basic idea out of it. Here is the link: <https://github.com/brow/leaves>

Comment: This is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983161/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-half-page/11032725#11032725

Comment: No, it's NOT answered there @DrMickeyLauer, the problem emenegro is facing (and I) is not because having a too big first-level children view, as he points out he has checked everything.

Comment: Please upload a minimal example that shows the problem and let us check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem. Same source code for iPhone and iPad, but the iPad version is curling the page too much, leaving a lot of free space. Then I tried to only put a label on the bottom of the iPhone version and the same thing happens.

**Explanation**: Apparently `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` always curls half the page, at minimum. The only reason in iPhone does not leave free space but it does in iPad is because, as the screen is much smaller, in iPhone usually your controls take not a lot less than half the page, which does not happen in iPad.

The only **workaround** I have found is re-designing the iPad layout so that your UI controls take more space, or just "living with it".