# Is it possible to use a page view controller to turn only a portion of the screen?

Tags: ios

I would like to split my screen (on the iPhone) into two where there is an upper and lower portions.
I'd like to programmatically animate the turning of the lower half of the screen.

I was just having a quick play around with the page view controller template within Xcode, however IB didn't permit me to change the size of the main view within the child view controller that comes as part of the template (I was going to experiment with reducing its size to the lower half of the screen).

Is this possible to achieve to get the page only animating on part of the screen?

(Its for iOS5 and 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The partial page curl is a way to present a modal view. Typically how far it page curls is determined by the views on the modal view controller (only put views on the bottom half and it only curls halfway). There are many questions detailing exactly how to get around having exactly half a view curl, but here is one of the [more common links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983161/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-half-page).